# Checking string contents

Tags: ruby

I have a string like this:

```
string1 = ",,"
```

I want to check if there are only commas in my string. Each time `string1` changes, it can have any number of commas. How can I check this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find number of `,`s in `string1` using this:

```
noc = string1.scan(/,/).size
# => 2
```

using this, you can verify if the string contains only `,`s by doing something like this:

```
string1=",,"
string1.scan(/,/).size == string1.size
# true

string1=",1,"
string1.scan(/,/).size == string1.size
# false
```

Answer (score 4):

A regex:

- Start of string: `\A`
- Comma: `,` (since it has no special meaning in regexes)
- 0+ occurrences of the previous matcher: `*`
- End of string: `\z`

  - Not `\Z`! That one's intended to ignore `\n` at the end, such as the result of `readline`

The condition is:

```
/\A,*\z/ =~ your_string
```

Comment: Check this with `"\n"`.

Comment: Thank you for preferring `\A` and `\z` over `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative range:

```
",," !~ /[^,]/
# => true
```

Comment: A nice way to avoid anchors.

Answer (score 2):

Just out of curiosity:

```
string1.tr(',', '').empty?
string1.delete(',').empty?
(string1.split('') - [',']).empty?
string1.codepoints.uniq == [44]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def all_commas? str
  str.squeeze == ','
end

all_commas? ','    #=> true 
all_commas? ',,,'  #=> true 
all_commas? '3,'   #=> false
all_commas? ' ,,,' #=> false 
all_commas? ',9,,' #=> false
```

Comment: If "there are only commas in my string" is supposed to presuppose that there is at least one comma, then you don't need to show your example with `''`. Otherwise, `all_commas? ''` is expected to return `true`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use this :

```
string.each_char.all? { |c| c == ',' } 
# && !string.empty? if the empty string is not valid
```

I think it's pretty expressive

Comment: A small point: consider using `each_char` to produce an enumerator instead of a temporary array.

Answer (score -4):

try this

```
string1=",,"

if string1.count(',,') == string1.length
   #here is your code 
end
```

Comment: The question stipulates that `string1` can have any number of commas

Comment: this will check that if string1 only have ',,' in the string